# Read oracle connection string from c#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a string

```
metadata=res://*/Mapping.Models.csdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string="data source=TESTSERVER;password=pass;persist security info=True;user id=id\"
```

How can I get the string as below:

```
data source=TESTSERVER;password=pass;persist security info=True;user id=id
```

Comment: Have you tried anything prior to asking?

Comment: @Matthijs I did. I tried Split.. But seem not ok with it...I dont really good in Regex...

Comment: Next time provide your efforts in your question! It shows that you have actively tried to solve your issue, which triggers SO-users to actively try to figure it out.

Comment: @Matthijs, ok, understood~

Comment: Duplicate of [Provider connection string from Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840896/provider-connection-string-from-entity-framework) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to substring connectionstring even that is possible using **EntityConnectionStringBuilder** as mentioned below :

```
var connString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringKey"].ConnectionString);
```

And from it you can retrieve **ProviderConnectionString** as shown below:

```
var providerString = connString.ProviderConnectionString;
```

**For Oracle:**

For oracle you can use [OracleConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi... Because I want to use OracleDependency but EF doesn't provide.. So I have to extract the Connection String.......... and use OracleConnection

Comment: @kingjia : For that you can use OracleConnectionBuilder. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to parse the string mentioned then you can use the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

There are Properties like ProviderConnectionString which gives you the string you want.

**Example**

```
var myEntityConnection = @"metadata=res://*/Mapping.Models.csdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connectionstring='""data source=TESTSERVER;password=pass;persist security info=True;user id=id";

var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(myEntityConnection);
Console.WriteLine(builder.ProviderConnectionString);
```

Thats all you Need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex to get the connection string if you want:

```
(data source).*[^"]
```

Comment: The order of elements within a provider connection string is arbitrary; the "data source" doesn't have to be the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try [splitting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) by the given delimiter. Then concatenate, the array elements.

string[] stringArray = str.Split(new string[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Comment: It will return original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Substring` by first seraching the sub-string `provider connection string=`:

```
int index = text.IndexOf(@"provider connection string=");
string result = text.Substring(index).Trim('"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\"[^\"]*\"
```

or

```
\".*?\"
```

explain :

```
[^ character_group ]
```

Negation: Matches any single character that is not in character_group.

```
*?
```

Matches the previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible.

and a sample code:

```
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString, "\"([^\"]*)\""))
Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
```

//or in LINQ

```
var result = from Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "\"([^\"]*)\"") 
         select match.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SubString logic.

```
        string strConnection = @"metadata=res://*/Mapping.Models.csdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string='""data source=TESTSERVER;password=pass;persist security info=True;user id=id";

        strConnection = strConnection.Substring(strConnection.LastIndexOf("data source"));
```

Comment: almost there.... but contain '\'
data source=TESTSERVER;password=pass;persist security info=True;user id=id\